# sql hierarchical queries

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I want to get the hang of oracle's connect by prior command. Eg. I have a Table of Projects and a table of Employees connected by a mapping table project_employee. Every employee worked on a list of projects. Now I want to get the connection between the employees and their "friendship". A Employee is a friend with every project member of the projects he worked in, and their friends are also the friends of the employee defined in the beginning. Eg. Project P1 was done by employee A, B and C. Project P2 by B and C. Project P3 by B and D. So Employee A knows B and C (because they worked togheter in P1) and even D (because A worked with B in P1, and B works in P3 with D). This should be able to be done by connect by prior queries... But I can't get the hang of how to..

Comment: This is very hard to understand.  Maybe some example data models, input, output expected etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: found a sample database here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-installation.html . Imagine the same thing with the projects using this database as projects = films and actor = employee. I want each actor who played in a film with one specific actor and the actors who played in a film with a actor who played with the defined actor in a film...

Comment: yeah, no one is going to go to another website and understand your changes, you want help put in at least enough effort to type in information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like:

```
select * 
  from table_of_Employees e  
 where e.employee_id IN (  
(select employee_id/*, level as lvl */
   from project_employee pe 
 connect by NOCYCLE prior project_id = project_id 
                and prior employee_id != employee_id 
  start with employee_id IN (:some_start_employee)
 )
```